# Pydev dialog crashes Eclipse Juno IDE

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just installed Pydev 3.7.1 into Eclipse Juno.  I created a sample project and added a new file.  When I try to edit the file to add source code, I immediately get the following dialog...

[image]

After closing the dialog, Eclipse shuts down and I get the following from Eclipse...

[image]

I've tried clicking on the buttons in the dialog, but, nothing seems to resolve the problem.  I have Java 7 installed as Pydev requires, so, I'm not sure I'm missing anything.  Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Never saw that error... I saw that you're using eclipse x64... is that java you're using (c:\windows\system32\javaw.exe) also a 64 bit java?

Comment: I actually have both 32 bit and 64 bit Java installed.  I've had no other problems with Eclipse before today.

Comment: Can you try with LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ (i.e.: if it works it's probably some misconfiguration there) -- also, it may be nice trying on an empty workspace.

Comment: Ok, I think I've been able to solve that: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/b56423e2ac8667572627bf1042d868c6310be3aa (so, will release a new 3.8 tomorrow with the fix -- so, please try it once it's out).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I installed update 3.8.  The problem still exists if I start from an existing work space.  Clicking either button will shut down Eclipse.  However, If I start from a clean work space, I can click the "later" button and continue working.  Once I return to the previously empty work space, though, the problem happens again.

Comment: If you use LiClipse, do you have the same problem?

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I haven't tried yet.  The whole point about loading Pydev plugin for Eclipse was the assumption that it would not require any other plugins.  If I have time, I'll try LiClipse.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't really happen (what I think is that it's a bug either in the java vm/browser integration -- that dialog appears for everyone the first time they open PyDev, for quite some time already, yet, this is the first report with that error... if you see the code in PyDev for that is quite simple: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/src/org/python/pydev/editor/PydevShowBrowserMessage.java so, using LiClipse which has a more controlled env is usually easier to detect such things).

Comment: Actually... taking a look at the code I reminded myself of a workaround you can do locally to skip that dialog: if you add to the vmargs in eclipse.ini -Dpydev.funding.hide=1 it should no longer show you that dialog initially :)

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Thanks.  Your work around does in fact let me work without the dialog crashing Eclipse.  I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: I am also having the same issue...
... the 3.8 update does not solve the problem!! I am running Juno 64bit on win7 and pydev 3.8 now. I do not mind popups, but things become frustrating when the pydev crashes the whole eclipse and the message comes up again and again. Almost feels like I got a virus or my computer got hi-jacked...

Has anyone found a solution to this problem? is there any anti-virus software that would allow me to continue using eclipse and pydev? PyDev is a great plugin and unfortunately currently it's useless.

Please post the solution!! Thanks!!

Comment: @JavaFan Please read this entire thread.  Especially my post right before yours.

Comment: @mirower, Thanks for the pointer.  Does adding 
-Dpydev.funding.hide=1 affect anything else or only that particular dialog window?  Thanks!!

Comment: Just to follow up on my own question:  adding Dpydev.funding.hide=1 solved the problem.  thank you @mirower and everybody!!  P.S. my naive recommendation would be to rework the dialog code so that we do not have to add anything into the -vmargs section...  Less is simpler and thus better, right?  thanks again!!

Comment: Fabio's workaround works for me. I think the problem is if you have a 32 bit JVM on your system somewhere, it can get confused.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny the comment helped a lot. Would you consider convert it to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround for this issue is adding:

-Dpydev.funding.hide=1

to the vmargs in eclipse.ini (so that it doesn't create that dialog)

Note that in theory this problem shouldn't happen... what seems to be the issue is that somehow creating/closing a browser in SWT crashes Eclipse (which is really unexpected).

The code may be seen at: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/src/org/python/pydev/editor/PydevShowBrowserMessage.java -- so, if someone with the problem could try to pinpoint if there's a workaround for it getting the Eclipse SDK/PyDev sources: http://pydev.org/developers.html and making a debug session, it'd be really nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Eclipe 64-bit on Ubuntu 14.04. Opening a .py file in Eclipse with PyDev installed opened a pop-up window for half a second and then Eclipse crashed without any warning output.

Adding "-Dpydev.funding.hide=1" at the end of the eclipse.ini file solved the problem...